# Proper way to specify the Rails::Engine for dependency gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm building a namespaced Rails Engine gem which will be extendable through additional gems.
For example: MyEngine is the main gem which will also be the namespace.
MyEngine-blog & MyEngine-support are optional gems to extend the MyEngine gem while inheriting the MyEngine namespace.

MyEngine-blog & MyEngine-support are dependent on MyEngine for core functionality and both gems will include `spec.add_dependency "synculus"` in their gemspec files.

What is the proper way to specify the `Rails::Engine` for the dependency gems?
Do I have to specify `class Engine < ::Rails::Engine` in each of the MyEngine-blog & MyEngine-support gem's engine.rb files?

```
# lib/myengine/engine.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
  end
end

# lib/myengine/blog/engine.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    module Blog
    end
  end
end

# lib/myengine/support/engine.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    module Support
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the way spree commerce is doing this with their 2.x release, they have a really great grasp on rails engines.

[Spree Commerce 2.x engine.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/engine.rb)